# Using broadband connection in java program

Tags: java, ipv6, ipv4

Can I use broadband connection(connected by either IPv4 or IPv6) in our java program as like JDBC connection? Or how simply I want to know how to control a broadband connection programmatically by using java connection if above is done.

Comment: What do you want to do to the broadband connection?  What do you mean by "control a broadband connection"?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Communicate between two endpoints?  Shutdown/startup the underlying ethernet connection?

Comment: This question does not make any sense. JDBC conntion has nothing to do with ethernet connection!

Comment: As broadband is means to bring internet to your system you are using. But my wireless broadband do not show how much data i have used, as I have limited connection with me. So controlling it means logging the information like data usage(like last usage in database), so there will not be to call customer care again and again, that what we are doing by making connecting ur front end to database using jdbc. If one we can control it... we can do various operations.

Comment: You could probably write a proxy in Java... but I bet there are some very economical routers (with possibly open source firmware) that has the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think if using firmware like [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) you can install [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) and monitor that through Java.

http://www.engadget.com/2006/08/01/how-to-measure-your-bandwidth-with-snmp/

Java stacks:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/SNMP.html

http://www.snmp4j.org/